# My ng-repeat only show the latest loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wanted to show all the things inside my array, but it only shows the latest loops. Below is my controller function:

```
/*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('statisticsApp', []).controller('myCtrl',
function ($scope, $http) {
"use strict";
return $http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "GatewayAPI.php",

}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.records = response.data;

    var mydata,myJSON,myresult,myjava, myobj;
    var i;
    var Result; 
    var chartResultTemp = [];
    var resultType = [];

    for(i=0; i<72;i++)
    {
        //storing data
        mydata = $scope.records.data[i];

        //retrieving data
        Result = mydata.data.substring(6,9); //throw this in 

        myobj = mydata.data.substring(3,4);
        resultType = mydata.data.substring(3, 4);

        if(resultType === "A") { //selects type = a
            chartResultTemp = mydata.data.substring(6,9);
        } ;

        $scope.test2=chartResultTemp; //this one
        $scope.test3 = resultType;

        console.log(Result);
        console.log(resultType);
    }




    $scope.gotTemp = false;
    $scope.gotHumidity = false;
    $scope.getSoilMoisture = false;

});

});
```

This is the code in my php where i list all the items in my array:

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="cd in test2">{{cd}}</li>
</ul>
```

And this is my current result as viewed in browser console:
[image]

As you can see from the console log, it only shows the latest loop. I wanted to show all the data inside the array. Is it because I have declared the array wrongly.

**UPDATE:**

so I have used `$scope.test2.push(chartResultTemp)`, it gave me an error:  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Then, i tried

```
if(resultType === "A") { 
   chartResultTemp.push([mydata.data.substring(6,9)]);
} ;
```

It works, but the problem is the items listed has brackets in it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push to the array

```
$scope.test2.push(chartResultTemp);
```

Comment: which means its an array again you need another ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

By using (`=`) you are assigning different values to the same scope in each iteration which ultimately holds the final value assigned to it. To store all the values, you have to create an array and `push` value from each iteration.

```
$scope.test2 = [];
for(let i=0; i<72; i++){
  .....
  .....
  $scope.test2.push(chartResultTemp);
  .....
  .....
```

Comment: I have tried your way but gave me an error (refer updated code above) and tried pushing somewhere else. But it gives me brackets when listing out the items in the array